# Splitting check digit from number into separate column on import into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm fairly new to MySQL and I've got a database that I'm putting together in MySQL for analytics purposes. It's built from flat files (each is several gigabytes) that are loaded in and normalized and linked. The data is static once it's in. Updates consist of truncating all of the tables and putting in fresh data, but it will have many demanding queries run against it.

Almost all of the keys are based on 10-digit numbers, with the last digit being a check digit. If I can split that check digit off into a separate column my keys can go from 8-byte bigints to 4-byte ints. That should be a HUGE performance boost.

Having a procedure that goes line by line through these tables would be very slow (the server is my desktop). Is there a more efficient way to split off these last digits into a separate column? Or am I totally barking up the wrong tree thinking this will improve performance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't *know* whether it will improve performance, then you should test the performance.

Comment: I can't test the performance until I've got it setup, which is the current problem.

Comment: To test performance of tables, create the tables, populate them with random-ish data, and measure performance. To test separating the check digit, write a SQL statement, write a sed script or an awk script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a 64-bit server then I doubt the move from 8byte (64bit) bigints to 4byte (32bit) ints will give you much (if any) of a performance boost - you'll still be doing most things in a single operation. It may well give you a decent sized drop in space used for the database, though.

If you want to go ahead and try it, I'd say the fastest way would be to substring the key when you're doing the original insert - you've already retrieved the data, so you don't have any need to SELECT or UPDATE, you just do slightly more work in the INSERT....which you're about to do anyway. The overhead of inserting into an extra field, and two substrings, should be minimal.